# Laravel post url parameters

Tags: laravel

So i've got a form on my page /post-form
The /post-form page also has parameters in it's URL like this /post-form?token={randomtoken}

I want it so that when I click on the submit button on the form I get the value of the token parameter.
My route looks like this

```
Route::post('/post-form', 'PostFormController@post')->name('post');
```

This is the action that happens when I click on the submit button on the form.
Does anyone know how to get the token parameter in the post function in my PostFormController?

Comment: have you tried `$token = request('token');`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I tried that but it's returning nothing so that's why I asked here

Answer (score 0):

```
public function post(Request $request){
  $token =$request->query('token');
}
```

you can see more [requests Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input)

Comment: It's still giving me nothing in return.

Comment: @Max is your server  nginx ? or you work with laravel artisan?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$token = $request->input('token');
```